# How to create web service to receive JSON?

Tags: json, web-services

I am new to web services. I need to create a web service that will receive JSON from a source in VB.NET. Could you please help on how to start with this?
Earlier I have called web service and received JSON from it after getting the HTTPResponse. But in this case, source will send the data and my web service need to receive it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After some google I was able to understand the WCF concept. All I did was create a contract with attributes as:

```
<OperationContract>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
           ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate:="InputData")>
```

for my method.

Then I added endpoint and binding as "webHttpBinding".
Created classes to deserialize JSON and I was good to go.